Required Deriv trading platform API documentation in python language
I do the following things: To install the deriv-api package, I use pip
pip install deriv-api   

Step 2 : Example Python script:
from deriv_api import DerivAPI

This above code code outputs:

ImportError: cannot import name 'DerivAPI' from 'deriv_api'

How to solve this?

Are you using virtual environments? You should run the code in the enviroment where the deriv_api library was installed. Use pip list to confirm the installation.

Dear Sir, now I am facing installation Error by using the command  pip install deriv-api .                 Is there any other pip command to Install  deriv-api Sir ?

Use python3 -m pip install python_deriv_api

Dear Sir, pip list shows only python_deriv_api, but not show the deriv_api. So, Same Error will be shown. ImportError: cannot import name 'DerivAPI' from 'deriv_api' . Is there any other pip command to Install deriv-api Sir ?

To import you have to use from deriv_api import DerivAPI. I try it and worked. Go to https://deriv-com.github.io/python-deriv-api to see python-deriv-api documentation.

Thank you Sir, I will check it and Update You Sir.
